# recursion on linear combination python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I have this interview practice question:

There exists a staircase with N steps, and you can climb up any number of steps from a set of positive integers X? For example, if X = {1, 3, 5}, you could climb 1, 3, or 5 steps at a time.

I got the below implementation and it seems to work.

I have a few questions on my approach :

1.What would be the Big-O notation for this piece of code ?

2.Would there be a better approach, taking in to consideration the complexity ?

```
def stairA(N,X):

    print("begin")
    print(N)
    print(X)
    print(len(X))
    print("end")
    total=0

    if(len(X)==0):
        print("space_Z")
        return 0

    if (len(X)>0):
        if(X[len(X)-1]>N):
            print("space_A")
            newlist = [k for k in X if k < X[len(X)-1]]
            stairA(N,newlist) #step size greater than stair number
            #stairA(N,X[:len(T)-1]) #step size greater than stair number
        if (N==1):
            if(1 in X):
                print("space_B")
                return 1

        if (N==0):
            print("space_X")
            return 1
        if (N<0):
            print("space_Y")
            return 0


        for ind,ele in enumerate(X):                          
            a=N-ele    

            stairA(a,X)#what first step we take
            total = total + stairA(a,X)#what first step we take

    return total
```

**Results:**

```
1+1+1+1

1+2+1

1+1+2

1+3

2+1+1

2+2

3+1

Y=[3,1,2]
Y.sort()
print(Y)
stairA(4,Y)
```

Comment: There is no question in the problem statement. What do you need to get? Also what do yo mean by `o(N)` - complexity?

Comment: Is the question printing all possible cases? Or just number of cases?

Comment: I got the solution. It says its the generalization of f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2) Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: def staircase(n, X):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return sum(staircase(n - x, X) for x in X)

Comment: It says this implementation is O(|X|**N) and it suggests use dynamic programming

Answer (score 0):

Recursion as this is the generation of f(N)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)+....

```
def staircase(n, X):
        if n < 0:
            return 0
        elif n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return sum(staircase(n - x, X) for x in X)
```

Dynamic programming:

```
def staircase(n, X):
    cache = [0 for _ in range(n + 1)]
    cache[0] = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        cache[i] += sum(cache[i - x] for x in X if i - x >= 0)
    return cache[n]
```

I cant figure out why the recursion one O(|X|**N)
and the dynamic one is O(N*|X|)